# What use does the with statement in python have in the standard library apart from interacting with files?

Tags: python

I am aware that the `with` statement allows context managers to 'clean up after themselves', but other than the well known

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

what uses does the `with` statement have utilizing *just* the standard library, *without* creating custom context managers?

Comment: To be clear: it sounds like this is similar to asking what context managers are provided by the standard library?

Comment: @DavidZ yes, unless there are uses for `with` that somehow do not involve context managers.

Comment: So look through the standard library to see which modules define context managers.

Comment: It might be easiest to just grep the source for `__enter__` or `@contextmanager`.

Comment: ah, apologies for the duplicate. I did search before, honest!

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, it's useful in Python threading (although geez, Python threading ain't ever that useful). https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement

Oh, and pool executors.

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for _ in range(10):
        executor.submit(some_func)
```